# Identifier not found on compiler (Free Pascal)

Tags: delphi, lazarus, freepascal

I'm trying to change the color of a panel on Lazarus on mouse hover.

I try run this code on Lazarus:

```
unit test;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
[...]

type

  { Tvendas_menu }

  Tvendas_menu = class(TForm)

    [...]
    procedure StartMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
    [...]


  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
[...]

implementation
[...]

procedure Tvendas_menu.StartMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Start.Color := $00E7E7E7;
end;
[...]
```

But when compiling the program show the following error code:

Error: Identifier not found "Start"

I'm sure that "Start" is the name of the panel on Object Inspector and .lfm file.

I try to change "Start" to another name but the error still occurs.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us _complete_ source code

Comment: Where is the declaration of the `Start` object in the `Tvendas_menu` you have shown? Clearly it is not in one of the `[...]` sections, or the compiler would not be complaining about it.

Comment: You removed the code that matters. Please take some time to learn how to make an MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add controls to the form they automagically get added under the form class, in your case they would appear under `Tvendas_menu = class(TForm)`.

One possibility of the error could be because the line `Start` is missing, you should have something like:

```
type
  Tvendas_menu = class(TForm)
    Start: TPanel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

To resolve this, try adding the line `Start: TPanel;` like above if it is not present.

One other option you have is to view the form in text view (`.lfm` for Lazarus and `.dfm` for Delphi) and find the reference block for `Start`, it may look something like:

```
object Start: TPanel
  Left = 152
  Top = 248
  Width = 185
  Height = 41
  Caption = 'Start'
  TabOrder = 1
end
```

Delete that and then return back to Form view.

Then you can try adding a new panel to the form and naming it `Start`, then you just need to link your event handlers back to the new control.

As a side tip, naming a control `Start` is not really very useful, maybe think of a better named identifier such as `panStart`.

Comment: I forgot to insert the "Start: TPanel;" below "Tvendas_menu = class(TForm)". Thanks!

Comment: But it should have been added there by the form designer, not by you. The form designer should have added it when you dropped the panel on the form. Did you manually edit the .lfm file, or what happened?